# upload image in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to upload image in codeigniter, but I got problem in , $this->upload->do_upload('imgname'). if condition not  execute, only elese execute and show error message is 'You did not selected file to upload'. but while remove the form upload in all code then it execute perfectly....

controller:

```
public function add_news()
    {
            $post = $this->input->post();

            unset($post['submit']);

            $this->load->model('Adminmodel','addNews');
            if(!is_dir('uploads'))
            {
                mkdir(base_url().'uploads',0777,true);
            }
            if(!is_dir('uploads/news'))
            {
                mkdir('uploads/news',0777,true);
            }


            $config = [ 
                        'upload_path'=>'uploads/news',
                        'allowed_types'=>'png|jpg|jpeg|gif',
                        'encrypt_name'=>'0777',
                      ];

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            if($this->upload->do_upload('newsimg'))
            {
                $data = $this->upload->data();
                $file_path = base_url().'uploads/news/'.$data["raw_name"].$data["file_ext"];
                $post['newsimg'] = $file_path;
                //$this->revEdit->reg_info($id,$post);
                $post['posted'] = date('d-m-Y');
                $this->addNews->store_news($post);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('newsAlert','Yeh! News Added Successfully.');
                redirect('Admin/news');
            }
            else
            {

                $newsdata = $this->addNews->news_list();
                $upload_error = $this->upload->display_errors();


                $this->load->view('Admin/news',compact('upload_error','newsdata'));
            }}
```

view:

```
<?=form_open('Admin/add_news',['class'=>'form'],['aid'=>$this->session->userdata('adminId')])?>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>News Heading</label>
          <?=form_input(['name'=>'title','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter News Title','value'=>set_value('title')])?>


        </div> 
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>News Details</label>
          <?=form_textarea(['name'=>'body','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter News Body','value'=>set_value('body')])?>


        </div>
              <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="PDF file only">
                  <span><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Select File&nbsp;<span id="Percentage" class="percentage text-center"></span></span>
                  <?=form_upload(['name'=>'newsimg','class'=>'upload','id'=>'file1','onchange'=>'loadPdf(event)'])?>

                </div>
              </div>

               <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div id="myProgress" class="progress">
                  <div id="myBar" class="bar progress-bar" role='progressbar'>  
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <?=form_reset('reset','Reset',['class'=>'btn btn-md btn-primary'])?>
    <?=form_submit('submit','Post',['class'=>'btn btn-md btn-success'])?>
  </div>
<?=form_close()?>
```

model:

```
public function store_news($array)
{
    return $this->db->insert('tbl_news', $array);
}
```

Comment: do you have `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in your form

Comment: Okey, Thank you  Regolith,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not using `enctype='multipart/form-data'` 
try this

```
<?=form_open_multipart('Admin/add_news',['class'=>'form'],['aid'=>$this->session->userdata('adminId')])?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `form_open_multipart` instead of `form_open` so that `enctype` can be added in form

Change

```
<?=form_open('Admin/add_news',['class'=>'form'],['aid'=>$this->session->userdata('adminId')])?>
```

to:

```
<?=form_open_multipart('Admin/add_news',['class'=>'form'],['aid'=>$this->session->userdata('adminId')])?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use multipart/form-data for file uploading.
So use form_open_multipart instead of form_open.

echo form_open_multipart('Admin/add_news');

Answer (score -1):

function upload_add($name) { $this->load->helper('form'); $config['upload_path'] = 'upload/add_image/'; $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; $config['max_size'] = '30000'; $config['max_width'] = '102400'; $config['max_height'] = '76800'; $this->load->library('upload', $config); $this->upload->initialize($config); if (!$this->upload->do_upload($name)) { $data = array('msg' => $this->upload->display_errors()); } else { $data = array('msg' => "success"); $databasea['upload_data'] = $this->upload->data(); $this->load->library('image_lib'); return $databasea['upload_data']['file_name']; } return ''; }